# OmniStudio licenses for Scratch Org

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, scratch-org, omnistudio

Does anyone know if it's possible to apply an OmniStudio license to a Scratch Org?
I'd like to install the OmniStudio managed package (outlined here: https://docs.vlocity.com/en/Prepare-to-Install-the-OmniStudio-Package.html) into a Scratch Org however I get the following errors when attempting to install:

> Installation errors:
>
> 1. (FlexCardDesigner) Validation Errors While Saving Record(s), Details: There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "The object type you specified OmniUiCard is invalid.".
> 2. (Vlocity_OmniScript_Designer) Validation Errors While Saving Record(s), Details: There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "The object type you specified OmniProcess is invalid.".

As per this document (https://docs.vlocity.com/en/OmniStudio-Permission-Set-Licenses.html) it seems that you need to assign the permission set licences prior to package install however these don't appear in my Scratch Org. Scratch Org definition file is as follows:

```
  "orgName": "Demo company",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": [
    "EnableSetPasswordInApi",
    "ServiceCloud",
    "ServiceUser",
    "PublicSectorAccess",
    "PublicSectorApplicationUsageCreditsAddOn",
    "PublicSectorSiteTemplate",
    "Knowledge",
    "LightningServiceConsole",
    "Interaction",
    "IndustriesActionPlan",
    "FlowSites",
    "API",
    "Communities",
    "PersonAccounts",
    "RecordTypes",
    "Workflow",
    "WorkflowFlowActionFeature"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    },
    "communitiesSettings": {
      "enableNetworksEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Although I wasn't able to find the right config file settings, using the new Org Shape feature (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_shape_enable_org_shape.htm) I was able to create a Scratch Org based on an existing PSS IDO with all of the OmniStudio features available.

Answer (score 2):

If you create the scratch org with the 'InsuranceCalculationUser' feature enabled, you can then install the Omnistudio package using sfdx force:package:install.

Page with versions:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000394906&type=1

Answer (score 0):

You can sign up for a developer edition with Omnistudio preinstalled:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/promo/orgs/omnistudiotrails